# reassmebly the raw data from IP packets into video

Tags: c, networking, youtube, video-streaming, sniffing

I have a simple sniffer which takes a packets from youtube while I am watching a video and I need to reassembly raw data from that packets into a video How is it can be done using C or C++
I have cut off IP and TCP headers already

Comment: Show what you've already tried.

Comment: The data might be mime-encoded to base64 and/or compressed and possibly even encrypted if youtube is doing https for video streams.  Also varies depending on whether or not your using the html5 interface (if the old one even still exists???).   Browsers sort all this out for you, which is way much video stream "rippers" are browser plugins, not packet sniffers.